# How to make this nav-bar display the needed links when user is signed in only in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying to make the nav bar show sign in and sign up buttons only when user is not signed in and show the message and profile nav items when the user is signed in.

Here is the code:

**token service**

```
...
  SetToken(token) {
    this.cookieService.set('chat_token', token);
  }

  GetToken() {
    return this.cookieService.get('chat_token');
  }

  DeleteToken() {
    this.cookieService.delete('chat_token');
  }

  GetPayload() {
    const token = this.GetToken();
    let payload;
    if (token) {
      payload = token.split('.')[1];
      payload = JSON.parse(window.atob(payload));
    }

    return payload.data;
  }
}
```

**Authguard service**

```
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const token = this.tokenService.GetToken();
    if (token) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

**header.ts**

```
  constructor(public nav: HeaderService, private tokenService: TokenService,
    private router: Router,
    private usersService: UsersService,
    private msgService: MessageService
  ) {
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
  } 

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.tokenService.GetPayload();
    ...
```

**HTML**

```
<nav *ngIf="nav.visible" class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="../assets/images/close.png" class="img-fluid" style="width:50px; height:50px" alt="">
  </a>

  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button"
  (click)="toggleNavbar()">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>


<div class="collapse navbar-collapse"
[ngClass]="{ 'show': navbarOpen }">
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home" >Item 1</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item signin">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/sign-in" >Sign in</a>
      </li>

       <li class="nav-item signup">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/sign-up" >Sign Up</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-auto" appdropdown #r="appdropdown">

          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle toolbar-image" href="" onclick="return false;" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              <i class="material-icons">forum</i>
            <span>2</span> 
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <div class="sidebar-scroll" id="list-group">
            <a class="dropdown-item chat" href="#">

                        <img src="http://emilcarlsson.se/assets/donnapaulsen.png" class="rounded-circle">
                        <div class='message'>
                        <h3 class="d-xs-none username">Jessica</h3>
                        <p class="d-xs-none letter">StanIsLove aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.</p>
                        </div>
                        <p>17m ago</p>
                      </a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown ml-auto" appdropdown #r="appdropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="" onclick="return false;" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <img src="http://emilcarlsson.se/assets/donnapaulsen.png" class="rounded-circle profile">
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right avatar" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                <div class="sidebar-scroll" id="list-group">
              <a class="dropdown-item chat" href="#">
                  <span class="d-xs-none username">Profile</span>  
                        </a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item chat" href="#">
                            <span class="d-xs-none username">Settings</span>  
                                  </a>
                                  <a class="dropdown-item chat" href="#">
                                    <span class="d-xs-none username">Logout</span>  
                                          </a>

                  </div>
              </div>


          </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I assume I should integrate **this.tokenService.GetPayload()** in HTML and use ng if but not sure if it will work. How can I solve this issue and show sign in and sign up links only for outside users and show the last 2 drop downs only for signed in users?

Comment: In your component, get your token from your tokenService, and set a boolean `isLogged` accordingly. Then in your template, display the menu with `*ngIf`

Comment: Thanks for replying @Florian can you please show it on an example?

Answer (score 1):

1.) you need to avoid calling `component's methods` inside your `html template`. An explanation can be found [here](https://blog.appverse.io/why-it-is-a-bad-idea-to-use-methods-in-the-html-templates-with-angular-2-30d49f0d3b16)

2.) Inside your `header-component.ts`, inject your service into constructor, add a class property, call your service to get token and set your class property accordingly.

```
export clas HeaderComponent implements OnInit:

  private isLogged: boolean;

constructor(private tokenService: TokenService){

  public ngOnInit() { 
    this.isLogged = this.tokenService.GetPayload() !== null; // here, I consider that user is logged if you have a payload, maybe you need to change the condition
  }
}
```

3.) Inside your `header.component.html`, check whether the user is logged or not to display your elements.

`<div *ngIf="isLogged">...</div>`

4.) Your method GetPayload() should be modified. In case you don't have a token, your code will throw `TypeError: Cannot read property data of undefined`

```
GetPayload() {
    const token = this.GetToken();
    if (!token) {
      return null;
    }
    const payload = Json.parse(window.atob(token.split('.')[1]);
    return payload.data;
  }
```

**Now that your method GetPayload can return null, be careful when you call the method, ensure that the result is not null before using it.**

Comment: Thank you so much. Looks what I needed. I will check it on my complete example and let you know :) 
In terms of methods which you said in the above your solution. I used only methods for Bootstrap 4 collapse since didn't want to use jquery instead.

Comment: @Artyom : nothing is wrong to call method on events (such as `click` in your example, because the method will only be called when event is fired)

Comment: When I include last part of the code in token service it shows red line under this code. Especially under Json and under last ;
const payload = Json.parse(window.atob(token.split('.')[1]);

Comment: @Artyom : do you have tslint or something activated ? If so, it might be because the line is pretty long, so you can split it. If you have a transcompilation error, copy/paste the error

Answer (score -1):

You can use a check if the user is logged in to disable / hide the links completely. This check should be sent by the server to your client and there should be a service which holds the login status to be asked by any component.
In your case you can add the structural directive `*ngIf="user"` inside your tags to check if the user is set and only display the links if it is set.

```
<li *ngIf="user" class="nav-item">
  <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home" >Item 1</a>
</li>
```

If you just want to secure routing, use the AuthGuard.
https://angular.io/guide/router#canactivate-requiring-authentication.